# Delimiter error in Informatica data transfer

Tags: etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-powerexchange

Actually I am trying to transfer data from one flat file to another using Informatica.

The delimiter is `|`, ex.

```
Animesh|Srivastava|lucknow
```

But in output file data is showing

```
"Animesh",|"Srivastava",|"Lucknow"
```

I cannot figure out from where `""` and `,` are being added.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change this in the session properties.

In workflow manager,

session --> Mapping tab --> Target

When you click on Target, you will find option called set file properties,

set file properties --> Advanced --> optional Quotes:

You will find None , Single and Double.

Select the option none. Default option is Double

[image]